# Printf command adding extra space in the line

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I am trying to create hdr record in unix script. I am using printf function to populate.  printf statement added 2 spaces in the line.

I am using below code for that

```
 REC_TYP="1"
 SYS_ID="AN"    #CR119
 SYS_FILE_NBR="03"
 DT_STAMP=`date +%Y%m%d`
 DT_STAMP=$(echo "$DT_STAMP" | tr -s " ")
 TI_STAMP=`date +%T`
 TI_STAMP1=$(echo "$TI_STAMP" | sed 's/://g')
 FILE_TXT="abc_FILE"
 echo "Date value:"$DT_STAMP
 echo "Timestamp:"$TI_STAMP1
 printf '%s%1s%2s%2s%8s%6s\n' $REC_TYP $SYS_ID $SYS_FILE_NBR $DT_STAMP $TI_STAMP1 #$FILE_TXT
```

I am expecting the output like below

```
 1AN0320230822024946abc_FILE
```

but I am getting output like below

```
 1AN0320230822  024946abc_FILE
```

Anyone help me where that 2 space adding in above code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printf '%s%2s%2s%2s%6s%6s\n' "$REC_TYP" "$SYS_ID" "$SYS_FILE_NBR" "$DT_STAMP" "$TI_STAMP1" "$FILE_TXT"
```

I guess you are having wrong widths and don't forget the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '%s%1s%2s%2s%8s%6s\n' $REC_TYP $SYS_ID $SYS_FILE_NBR $DT_STAMP $TI_STAMP1
#                  ^^^
```

Your 5th parameter is left-padded to a width of 8 chars, but the value (`162659`) is only 6 characters wide. Padding by default happens with a space character. Either set the correct width or don't set the width at all.

Other things to note:

- Always quote your parameters when expanding
- You are not passing an argument for your last placeholder, so the output string will always end with 6 spaces